# Why do the Gold and Silver Brothers in Naruto Shippuden have whisker marks?

Tags: naruto

I recently watched episode 269, and in a flashback, they had whisker marks BEFORE they got swallowed by Kurama (Nine-Tails) and started eating its flesh.

Comment: Most likely an animation error. Nice catch though!

Comment: Would you please edit to add a screenshot in?

Comment: if you are trying to say that whisker marks should be after possession of Kyubi then you are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the author is making a reference to the [Maneki-Neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneki-neko) or the fortune cat with the whiskers. It is a tradition that these ornaments brings forth good luck or fortune. Back in the old days, copper, silvers and gold were used as part of the currency exchange, that is why the Maneki Neko is sometimes coated in gold like color.

Towards the end before the Gold and Silver brothers were completely sealed away, Darui did mention something about if a bunch of copper work together, it is worth more than a lump of gold or silver.

Comment: And how does this answer the question about a possible mistake in animation?

Comment: This is not a mistake in animation error. As I said, the author symbolizes the Gold and Silver brothers with Maneki-Neko (which is a cat). So the whisker traits was inherited from the Maneki Neko, NOT THE 9 TAILS.

Comment: its more likely just sloppy animation/after thought.  Naruto had whisker marks before he got infused with nine tails also.

Comment: Naruto had whisker marks because he was in the womb of the Kyuubi's Jinchuuriki. It is known. I came here because I'm also wondering about those guys. The cat whiskers might make sense unless it is indeed an animation error. But, it can't be, because they shouldn't be taking traits from the kyuubi like naruto did.